# Redirect based on country in next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm new to Next.js, and I want to redirect user to default page when he visit the website
for example if the country of the user is`us` I want to redirect him to `domain.com/us` and so on
here is my tries:

```
type Middleware = (req: NextRequest) => Promise<NextResponse>;

export const middleware: Middleware = async (req) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://ip-api.com/json`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.country === "Egypt") {
        console.log('Egypt')
        const newPath = `/egypt${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`;
        const newUrl = new URL(newPath, req.url);

        // Redirect with the new URL
        return NextResponse.redirect(newUrl, { status: 301 });
    } else {
        return NextResponse.next();
    }

};

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        /*
         * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
         * - api (API routes)
         * - static (static files)
         * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
         * - _next (debug files)
         */
        "/((?!api|static|favicon.ico|_next|_next/image|images).*)"
    ]
};
```

and the issue with my try is I have this error`err_too_many_redirects`

Comment: Do you have the redirect functionality  on the pages you redirect to?

Comment: @MartinKalling I want to apply it in all website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, the issue is that after you redirect the user, it is causing the middleware to rerun (and redirect) the user again. This can be solved a number of ways, with the best being to check the URL to see if it already has the geo-tag.

Add this to the middleware 'if Egypt' function before redirecting, to ensure that you don't get the 'err_too_many_redirects' error:

```
if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/egypt')) {
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```